# CSRF Cookie Missing - EventLog Error hints at MS Office

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, csrf, kentico, csrf-protection

Kentico 10 operating on a Windows Server.
I'm getting the following error in the Event Log several dozen times per hour: 
**The CSRF cookie was missing.**

The error occurs on my production server only, not any of the development environments, and I have not been able to find a way to manually reproduce it myself (I just see it in the log). This leads me to believe that it is related to sort of strange incoming traffic to the production site (as opposed to a problem with our application code itself)

The issue is also difficult to locate because the event URL listed is always shown as: /cmsmessages/error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/cmspages/portaltemplate.aspx

The only clue I have is that all of the User Agents have some form of a Microsoft Office or ExchangeService product name in them:

- MacOutlook/14.7.7.170905 (Intel Mac OS X 10.9.5)
- Mac OS X/10.12.6 (16G1036); ExchangeWebServices/7.2 (268); accountsd/113 (113)
- Microsoft Office/15.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Excel 15.0.4989; Pro)
- Microsoft Office/16.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Word 16.0.8625; Pro)

Could it be some strange "protected view" browser from an Office application loading the page and refusing cookies? Any thoughts on how to fix this error?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before - as I recall it's external sources looking for something on your domain.  By the agents you're seeing, I'd say it was exchange/email related (perhaps people opening emails you send out?).

Someone describes a similar issue here: https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/csrf-attack-detected-on-live-site-when-using-smart-search

While not ideal, you can disable CSRF using the application settings key `<add key="CMSEnableCsrfProtection" value="false" />`.

Comment: I agree with Matt on this and my answer is part of the topic he posted. It seems, that some mail clients are raising POST requests. This is something that had appeared multiple times recently and it seems to be a nature of email clients. However these can be ignored as false positive, although you can check IIS logs for request details to see what was actual request during that time and this way you should be able to at least specify page that is appearing in emails.

Comment: Thanks you two! Any chance it might be related to this LivePreview:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-link-to-an-email-using-Link-Preview-in-Outlook-com-or-Outlook-on-the-web-ebbfd8ce-d38e-40ef-bb8c-a5362e881163

Noticing that a majority of the errors are coming from the clients IP, and it would make sense that they are sending a lot of links to their site via email.

Comment: Or this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-365-ATP-safe-links-dd6a1fef-ec4a-4cf4-a25a-bb591c5811e3#atpforemail if a user clicks on a link and its redirected by ATP via a POST

Comment: Hi @JohnHorton, can you point me to where it mentions redirecting via POST, can't see it in that link?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the UAs that are being logged this seems to be related to [Microsoft's EWS API](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/blob/master/Core/ExchangeServiceBase.cs). It seems rather strange that these requests hit your Kentico website though, given the fact that this is something you don't expect to be happening.

Kentico's CSRF protection will by default block any POST requests without proper CSRF tokens. Disabling the CSRF will put your users and website and risk, so I highly recommend keeping it enabled.

As mentioned earlier, you should check your IIS logs to get more information about these requests, mainly the actual request URL. In case you are still not able to determine where these request originate from and they are not expected, I suggest you set up a rule to block them. This can be done either using a WAF or IIS.